# When do we call some elements as extensible in WSDL?

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I am new to web-services concepts and learning details on [WSDL from online documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_language) and came across `extensibility elements` in `WSDL`.

Please help me in understanding what are these elements and why do we call them as `extensible`? When a WSDL element is called as extensible?

I observed that this term is not specific to `XMl`, is that correct?

Experienced developers, please provide your valuable answers so it helps for me a lot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This link - [Configuring WSDL Extensibility Elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-3490/cnfg_wsdl-exten-elem_r/index.html) has some information on what are extensibility elements.

> Each binding components contain protocol-specific information, defined
>   by WSDL Extensibility Elements.

So protocol specific details are called as `extensibility elements`. The protocol can be `SOAP`, `HTTP` or `MIME`. Since it facilitates the option for the user to select a protocol it is called as `extensibility elements`.